# Error in web.xml file when I add context-parameters to it

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am getting an error in web.xml file while adding context parameters to it.
Here is web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<context-param>
    <pram-name>ADMIN_PATH</param-name>
    <param-value>AdminChatServlet</param-value>
</context-param>      
<context-param>
    <param-name>ROOMLIST_PATH</param-name>
    <param-value>/RoomListServlet</param-value> 
</context-param>    
<context-param>
    <param-name>CHROOM_PATH</param-name>
    <param-value>/ChRoomServlet</param-value>
</context-param>  
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MainChatServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>AdminChatServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RoomListServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>RoomListServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ChRoomServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ChRoomServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MainChatServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AdminChatServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RoomListServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RoomListServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ChRoomServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ChRoomServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

and here is the servlet(MainChatServlet) using those context-parameters:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.amir.*;
public class MainChatServlet extends HttpServlet {

 String chRoomPath;//="ChRoomServlet.java";
 String roomListPath;//="RoomListServlet.java";
 String adminChatPath;//="AdminChatServlet.java";

 public void init()
 {
 ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
 context.setAttribute("chRoomPath",context.getInitParameter("CHROOM_PATH"));
 context.setAttribute("roomListPath",context.getInitParameter("ROOMLIST_PATH"));
context.setAttribute("adminChatPath",context.getInitParameter("ADMINCHAT_PATH"));
 }

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,  IOException
 {
  doPost(request, response);
 }

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,  IOException
{       
   HttpSession session =  request.getSession();

   chRoomPath = (String)getServletContext().getAttribute("chRoomPath");
   roomListPath = (String)getServletContext().getAttribute("roomListpath");
   adminChatPath = (String)getServletContext().getAttribute("adminChatPath");

   session.setAttribute("chRoomPath",chRoomPath);
   session.setAttribute("roomListPath", roomListPath);
   session.setAttribute("adminChatPath",adminChatPath);

   HashMap hashmap = null;
   try
   {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/chat","root","mysql");

      synchronized(getServletContext())
              {
                hashmap = (HashMap)getServletContext().getAttribute("chatList");
                if(hashmap == null)
                {
                  hashmap =new HashMap();
                  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from chatrooms");
                  while(rs.next())
                  {
                    hashmap.put(rs.getString(1),new ChatRoom(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),4));                        
                  }
                  rs.close();
                  getServletContext().setAttribute("roomList", hashmap);
                }
               }    
      conn.close();
   }
   catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
   {
      System.out.print("Error(Class)");
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(SQLException e)
   {
      System.out.print("Error(SQL)");
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("chat.jsp");
   view.forward(request, response);

  }
}
```

and here is the default-package in which all the .java files(servlets are kept)

**Screenshot#1**

[image]

Why am I getting the error in the web.xml file?

**Screenshot#2**

[image]

**EDIT**: OR Suggest me any alternate idea if possible.

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo but your very first "param-name" is "pram-name".

Comment: Why don't you read the error message? A good error message already represents the answer at its own.